# Can you install AX 2012 and Dynamics CRM 2011 on a single server?

Tags: dynamics-crm, axapta

I would like to install an application server that runs both AX 2012 and CRM 2011 (upgraded to 2013).

I would like to run it on a single server.

I have checked and there are no port conflicts, so should theoretically be possible.

Is there any thing besides ports that could cause this to fail?

Comment: I guess the fastest way to get an answer is trying. Then answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just installed AX 2012 R2 side by side with CRM 2013. No major issues. SQL on another box and seems to be working just fine.